# Spring registerShutdownHook() not working but close() works

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I was using the following code:

```
ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
(ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).close();
```

The above works fine and destroys the beans created.
But when I do this:

```
ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
((AbstractApplicationContext) context).registerShutdownHook();
```

Beans are not destroyed and application is not closed. What am I missing here?
Changing `ApplicationContext` to `AbstractApplicationContext` also did not work.

Comment: The shutdown hook, as the name implies, is called when the jvm is shutdown that isn't happening and thus the app will keep running. Explicitly calling close will destroy the context.

Comment: ohh I see...calling System.exit() closed the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As corrected by [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) registerShutdownHook will close only when the JVM is shutdown which was not happening in my case.

To close the process I used `System.exit(0)` and then the application was closed and the beans were destroyed